# Writing a resolver to just transform the case

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Is there a cleaner way of writing this ? I am having to write a resolver just because the fields are in snake case on the backend.

```
const resolvers = {
    MyObj:{
        propertOne :({property_one}) => property_one,
        propertTwo:({property_two}) => property_two,
        propertThree:({property_three}) => property_three,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to accommodate the front end by serving it JSON objects with camel cased keys, then you are better off refactoring your renaming logic using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11) (or [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/)).

More specifically its [camelCase](https://lodash.com/docs/#camelCase) and [mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapKeys) methods and call the renaming logic it at the end of your resolvers, before they return their results.

I was in this specific case, and thought about adding a middleware to GraphL responses, but did not find any standard way of doing so.